# Why the first \t doesn't work?

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
    int toes = 10;
    printf("toes=%d\t2toes=%d\ttoes2=%d\n",toes,toes+toes,toes*toes);
    return 0;
}
```

//This is an exercise from c primer plus. After compiling and running, only the second \t works.

Comment: What do you mean with _\t doesn't work_?

Comment: It works, but it doesn't take more than one space in the visual representation? Try to run it trough a hexdump, or copy&paste it to an editor where there is special visualization of whitespace characters.

Comment: A tab does not insert x spaces. It aligns the output to columns in the console window.

Comment: here tab is for 4 places. So in case of first `\t` it will show only one space as first there places are occupied by the first three characters i.e. `=10`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I gave you an example of a better way to format output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine for me. ([example](http://rextester.com/GPNHLZ91038))

Output:

```
toes=10 2toes=20        toes2=100
```

Note that `\t` means "*tabulate*", or in other words to pad to the nearest multiple of *N* position, where *N* is usually 8.

`toes=10` takes up 7 characters, so to reach the next multiple of 8 would require printing 1 space.

Comment: `2toes=20` takes up 8 characters, so aligning to the next multiple of 8 will require printing 8 spaces (assuming tab size is 8).

Comment: Answers relying on an external link are useless. And there is a close-reason if there is no problem in the question.

Comment: Excuse me?? Then show me a way to compile and run a C program directly on SO.

Comment: And if the external site goes offline? Why do we need to compile the code online? Take the [tour], read the FAQs!

Comment: Dude. Chill. The link is not essential to this answer at all.

Comment: A more formal language would be appropriate. I'm not your "dude" and I don't have to chill. Whatever you smoke.

Comment: I've printed the same output twice in here [link](https://ideone.com/V7YNBt) and it takes just one space after `toes=10` both the times. Is this because of online editor?

Answer (score 2):

Tabs indent text to fixed positions. This means, that they don't make 4-space gap but make a gap until matching next flagged position.

```
toes=10 2toes=20        toes2=100
1234567812345678123456781234567812345678
```

It's an unlucky example. Your tabs are 8 long. So they stop every 8 letters. If you added one space before first `\t` your tab would make a bigger gap.

Better output formatting would be achieved by:

```
printf("%s%s%s\n", " single", " double", " square");
printf("%7d%7d%7d\n", toes, 2*toes, toes*toes);
```

Output:

```
 single double square                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     10     20    100
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working, but it seems like it is not !!!

This is because by default you have a `tabspace` equal to `8` `spaces`. And `toes=10` takes up `7` spaces, and only `1` space if left for the `\t` to fill.

To see that it is working change your `printf` to:

```
printf("ts=%d\t2toes=%d\ttoes2=%d\n",toes,toes+toes,toes*toes);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `\t` character won't take always the same space, it will adjust to a column.

If you want a fix number of spaces between your entries, input them manually between your values.